# Can you help me understand how the Rcode Which function works in this context

Tags: r, function

So I am trying to convert an AI pathfollowing algorithm over from R Code to C++ for an assignment in class and Ive come across the Which function from the R library and I cant figure out what it does. I've read the documentation of the which function but it does not mention anything about using a > symbol in it.

The line is

```
i <- max(which(param > path$param))
```

param is a double that ranges anywhere between 0 and 1 and the path&param is a list of double values anywhere between 0 and 1

Ive watched in the debugger and "i" always returns as a whole number like 1 2 or 3

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `which()` evaluates the logical expression and returns the index of observations that evaluate to TRUE. So in this case you are going to get the index of the last observation in `path$param` that is smaller than `param`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# example data:
> param = 2
> path = data.frame(param = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1))

> param > path$param
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> which(param > path$param)
[1]  1  4  8 11

# so which() is similar to np.where() in Python
# it returns indexes of where the expression evaluated to TRUE

> max(which(param > path$param))
[1] 11

> i <- max(which(param > path$param))
# so i is 11 in this example
```